# SQL select multiple rows into one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with related data across multiple rows that I need to query as one row IF the meta_key value is in `('A', 'B', 'C')`.

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
--------+---------+----------+-----------
   1    |  1234   |    A     |    Foo
   2    |  1234   |    B     |    Bar
   3    |  1234   |    C     |    Baz
   4    |  1234   |    D     |    junk
```

What I am looking to end up with is a query that gives me results

**Output**

```
 A  |  B  |  C
----+-----+----
Foo | Bar | Baz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get such a result. This assumes there is one meta_value per meta_key for a given post_id.

```
select 
max(case when meta_key='A' then meta_value end) as A,
max(case when meta_key='B' then meta_value end) as B,
max(case when meta_key='C' then meta_value end) as C 
from yourtable
group by post_id
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply run this SQL conditional query command:

SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE meta_key='A' AND meta_key='B' AND meta_key='C'

To limit the query results, do:

SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE meta_key='A' AND meta_key='B' AND meta_key='C' LIMIT 10

Note: the LIMIT keyword accept any valid range of integers.

Comment: A record in the table cannot have the value 'A' and 'B' and 'C' in the field meta_key at the same moment, but only one of them.